# subtotals and grand total in js invoice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't figure out how to do what I want to, so I'll do it the ugly way.

I have been trying for a week to get this invoice system done with JS, I am stuck.

I have been able to get `price per * quantity = subtotal` to work, but only for one line, I need to add 3 more lines for the invoice but have absolutely no idea how to incorporate the other 3 lines, each one with `price per * quantity = subtotal`, then all 4 subtotals from that column summed together in the TOTAL span, I will post all the code here.

**JavaScript:**

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var a = document.getElementById('price');
var a = document.getElementById('qty');
item.onchange = function() {
    price.innerHTML = "$" + this.value;
    qty.value = 1; //Order 1 by default.
    add();
};
qty.onchange = function() {
    add();
}

function add() {
    var a = document.getElementById('item').value,
        b = document.getElementById('qty').value;

    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "$" + (a * b);
    document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = "$" + (a * b) * 1.06;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form name="frm">
<p><img src="strata/longwaylogoblk.png" width="230" height="50"></p>
<p>Customer Invoice</p>

<table width="38%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="31%"><div align="left">Eclipse Cellular</div></td>
    <td width="23%">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="10%">Name</td>
    <td width="36%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="left">2441 Foothill Blvd #1143</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Address</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="left">Rock Springs, WY, 82901</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="left">307-212-6886</div></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />

<table id="invoice" width="43%" border="0">
  <tr bgcolor="#B80000">
    <td width="9%"><div align="center">ID</div></td>
    <td width="31%">
      <div align="center">Item Description</div>
    </td>
    <td width="17%">
      <div align="center">Price Per</div>
    </td>
    <td width="13%">
      <div align="center">Quantity</div>
    </td>
    <td width="13%">
      <div align="center">SubTotal</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">1</div></td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <select name="item" id="item" size="1">
          <option value="">Device</option>
          <option value="200">iPhone 4</option>
          <option value="300">iPhone 4S</option>
          <option value="450">iPhone 5</option>
          <option value="300">Galaxy S3</option>
          <option value="450">Galaxy S4</option>
          <option value="450">Galaxy Note ll</option>
          <option value="600">Galaxy Note lll</option>
          <option value="700">Galaxy S5</option>
          <option value="500">HTC One</option>
          <option value="650">HTC One M8</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td height="43">
      <div align="center"><span id="price"></span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <input name="qty" type="Text" id="qty" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <span id="result"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">2</div></td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <select name="item1" id="item1" size="1">
          <option value="">Device</option>
          <option value="200.00">iPhone 4</option>
          <option value="300.00">iPhone 4S</option>
          <option value="450.00">iPhone 5</option>
          <option value="300.00">Galaxy S3</option>
          <option value="450.00">Galaxy S4</option>
          <option value="450.00">Galaxy Note ll</option>
          <option value="600.00">Galaxy Note lll</option>
          <option value="700.00">Galaxy S5</option>
          <option value="500.00">HTC One</option>
          <option value="650.00">HTC One M8</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td height="43">
      <div align="center"><span id="price1"></span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <input name="qty1" type="Text" id="qty1" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <span id="result1"></span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">3</div></td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <select name="item2" id="item2" size="1">
          <option value="">Service</option>
          <option value="35.00">Activation</option>
          <option value="20.00">ESN Change</option>
          <option value="20.00">Number Change</option>
          <option value="60.00">Flashing</option>
          <option value="25.00">Discount Activation</option>
          <option value="5.00">Rent To Own Late Fee</option>
          <option value="150.00">R2O Down Payment</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td height="43">
      <div align="center"><span id="price2"></span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <input name="qty2" type="Text" id="qty2" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div align="center"><span id="result2"></span></div>
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">4</div></td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <select name="item3" id="item3" size="1">
          <option value="">Airtime</option>
          <option value="12.00">PagePlus The 12</option>
          <option value="29.95">PagePlus Talk n Text 1200</option>
          <option value="39.95">PagePlus Unlimited Talk n Text</option>
          <option value="55.00">PagePlus The 55</option>
          <option value="69.95">PagePlus Super User</option>
          <option value="10.00">10 Cash PIN</option>
          <option value="25.00">25 Cash PIN</option>
          <option value="50.00">50 Cash PIN</option>
          <option value="80.00">80 Cash PIN</option>
          <option value="5.00">International (X$5)</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td height="43">
      <div align="center"><span id="price3"></span></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div align="center">
        <input name="qty3" type="Text" id="qty3" size="2" maxlength="3"/>
      </div>
    </td>

    <td>
      <div align="center"><span id="result3"></span></div>
    </td>
    <td>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center"></div></td>
        <td><div align="center"></div></td>
        <td height="44">
          <div align="center"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div align="center"><font color="#336699" size="3"><b>TOTAL:</b></font></div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div align="center"><span id="Total"></span></div>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><div align="center"></div></td>
        <td height="44"><div align="right">
          <input type="button" value="Exit" onclick="window.location.reload();" />
        </div></td>
        <td><div align="right">
          <input name="add" type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('invoice')"/>
        </div></td>
        <td><div align="center">
            <input name="save" type="button" value="Save" />
        </div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I know I have the TOTAL span wrong, but you get the idea, working version [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gomoguy/eCu39/4/)

Comment: Without having analysed the problem; you would do yourself a favour to use a client templating engine for this like underscore or handlebars.  Doesn't take long to learn.

Comment: I recently did this exact thing with jQuery. What you need to do is loop through your page adding up each qty and price and then your subtotal span and storing that in a variable which is your total subtotal. You can iterate through tables quite easily if you give it a Google

Comment: Lol. Thanks for the info, I am so new with js, I don't even understand half of it. I'm off to learn about looping!! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

copy this code

```
var item = document.getElementById('item');
var item1 = document.getElementById('item1');
var item2 = document.getElementById('item2');
var item3 = document.getElementById('item3');

item.onchange = function() {
  add();
};
item1.onchange = function() {
  add();
};
item2.onchange = function() {
  add();
};
item3.onchange = function() {
  add();
};
  function add() {
      var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
      var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');

      var total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
        var sum = 0;
        var price = (parseFloat(selects[i].value) )?parseFloat(selects[i].value):0;
        var qty = (parseFloat(inputs[i].value) )?parseFloat(inputs[i].value):0;
        sum += price * qty;
        total += sum * 1.06;
        if(i == 0){
          document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "$" + sum;
        }else{

          document.getElementById('result'+i).innerHTML = "$" + sum;
        }             
      };

      document.getElementById('Total').innerHTML = "$" + total;
  }
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help coder_ck, but it doesnt work. I copied the code and checked through it as best I could to find the problem, but it does nothing. But thank you for the help, I will keep working on it.

Comment: a little tweaking and i got it working perfectly, thanks